# Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - tmp/rspec_guard_result

Tags: guard, tmp

**ENV**

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

`Rails 4.2.0`

`Guard version 2.13.0`

**Problems:**

I think it's not because of spec itself, since it works normally when typed `bundle exec rspec xxx_spec.rb`

I run a `rm -rf /tmp` in accident before running this command, I think it's the reason of error in `tmp/rspec_guard_result`. But have no idea with how to solve it.

After running all specs, it shows following results:

**Result**

```
Finished in 1 minute 15.84 seconds (files took 0.46012 seconds to load)
177 examples, 1 failure, 3 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/xxxxxx_spec.rb:88 # xxxx valid should xxxxxx
07:36:42 - ERROR - Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its <run_all>, exception was:
> [#a47cf0a740cd] Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - tmp/rspec_guard_result
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:79:in `delete'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:79:in `_command_output'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:100:in `_process_run_result'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:45:in `block in _run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:44:in `tap'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:44:in `_run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:24:in `run_all'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec.rb:33:in `block in run_all'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec.rb:48:in `_throw_if_failed'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.5.0/lib/guard/rspec.rb:33:in `run_all'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:82:in `block in _supervise'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:79:in `catch'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:79:in `_supervise'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in _run_group_plugins'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:117:in `each'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:117:in `block in _run_group_plugins'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:116:in `catch'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:116:in `_run_group_plugins'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:20:in `each'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:20:in `block in run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/lumberjack-1.0.10/lib/lumberjack.rb:32:in `unit_of_work'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:18:in `run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:82:in `run_all'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/internals/queue.rb:42:in `block in _run_actions'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/internals/queue.rb:37:in `each'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/internals/queue.rb:37:in `_run_actions'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/internals/queue.rb:21:in `process'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:43:in `start'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/cli/environments/valid.rb:16:in `start_guard'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:122:in `start'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:32:in `execute'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:19:in `execute!'
> [#a47cf0a740cd] /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.13.0/bin/_guard-core:11:in `<main>'
07:36:42 - INFO - Guard::RSpec has just been fired
[1] guard(main)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to open an issue in Guard-RSpec for theses kinds of things. (You'll get a response and fix faster, and you'll know when fixes are released, etc.).

First, upgrade to guard-rspec 4.6.5. That's just to make sure you aren't having other problems.

Now, you have 2 options:

1. Avoid removing the whole `tmp` directory, and just remove the files you created there. This is the "nicest" solution, since multiple tools can create files there.
2. If you really want to remove `tmp` by yourself, then just manually set the `results_file` option to something other than tmp/rspec_guard_result, e.g.

   ```
   guard :rspec, results_file: 'guardfile_results.txt' do
   ```

Comment: But 1 not worked well. I removed the file "app/tmp/guardfile_results", but is still show same error. How can I recover that file?

Comment: The file is created automatically by guard-rspec when you start rspec tests, and it is deleted when the rspec tests finish (or fail). That file is where guard-rspec stores the results of the tests, if you have to make sure you don't remove that file yourself. If you remove it, guard-rspec cannot report the results of the specs properly. So instead of removing tmp, just remove all the files except guardfile_results, so guard-rspec can create and delete it itself.

Comment: thks, currently I touched a empty file named **rspec_guard_result** and **guardfile_results**,`-rw-rw-r--` in  `app/tmp/` folder, but it's seems haven't create and delete by itself. stll shows same error

Comment: You can change it to `guard :rspec, results_file: File.expand_path('guardfile_results.txt') do` and guard-rspec should create and remove the file in your project directory. That way you can remove the tmp dir and not care. If you still get an error, open an issue on the project's GitHub page and paste the exact output (the path matters).